# Some text moves when deleting a color swatch (Indesign CC)

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, swatches

I have a color swatch I need to be deleted, but on deleting the swatch some text in certain text frames moves up a little (1 or 2 mm). It is not the frames that move, but the text inside the frames. All text formatting parameters seem unchanged after deleting the swatch. This swatch is supposedly unused, but Indesign doesn't mark it as unused when I instruct to "Select all unused swatches".

I need to do this with fairly complicated documents, so keeping track of what elements exactly shift when doing this and putting them back in place is rather tedious. Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Swatch isn't mistakenly used as a stroke on the text is it?

Comment: What Scott said makes perfect sense and InDesign tells you it's used! Replace that color with another one or fix this manually.

Comment: No, the text doesn't have a stroke and if I replace with another color exactly the same happens.

Comment: I have encountered something similar in CS6; on deleting a colour swatch, some of the text changes from 8pt to 7! Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Are they actually moving? This could only be a preview issue. You could check the X,Y text frame position and font settings (point size, leading, etc) before and after removing the swatch. I would assume these numbers stay the same, which would mean nothing actually really moves.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that InDesign will often shift items very slightly on a page when I've been working on object styles or Master pages. It seems to be a visual hint that something is changing, but not necessarily that the text has moved. What I'd suggest is setting up some guides around your text to check positioning. If you delete the swatch, notice the text move, but then zoom in close, you might find that it hasn't actually physically shifted.